# ValueMember wrong in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

The class below is the data source for the combo of datagridview:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

The next is the data source for the datagridview:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
}
```

For simplicity, I will carry them with fixed values, but similar to my real case:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bdsCustomer.DataSource = new List<Customer>
                                     {
                                         new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Paulo", City = "City A"},
                                         new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Tatiane", City = "City B"},
                                         new Customer {Id = 3, Name = "Paulo", City = "City C"},
                                     };

        bdsOrder.DataSource = new List<Order>
                                  {
                                      new Order {Id = 1, IdCustomer = 1, RequestDate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 25)},
                                      new Order {Id = 2, IdCustomer = 2, RequestDate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 26)},
                                      new Order {Id = 3, IdCustomer = 3, RequestDate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 27)}
                                  };


    }
```

I'll let the field "IdCustomer" in datagridview to display the problem and I'll create a new field with the combo:
[image]

Notice in the image that the "IdCustomer" field of the first record is correct and presenting the Id 1:
[image]

Now I will select the other "Paul" with the Id 3 and see what happens to the value of IdCustomer:
[image]

Even selecting the client with the Id 3, the Id continues 1. You can have 10 clients "Paul", anyone who select the IdCustomer does not change.

What can I do?

I solved the problem, I used the DevExpress grid, is now working perfectly!
[image]

Comment: You just can't have two display items that are the same display.  How would the end user know which Paulo to select from the drop down?

Comment: @LarsTech, I really found it strange the possibility, but as I did not think anything about not being able to use duplicate values decided to post to know if there is a solution or if it's a bug, thank you!